# Extracting Data from Pinterest using BeautifulSoup, Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pinterest

I'm trying to extract pinterest data such as title of a pin, image description such as alt, src, comments/description, creator. Since my api hasn't yet been approved, I'm trying to do web scraping using BeautifulSoup, Python. The limitation I could see is, it retrieves only 16 alt, src no matter which query keyword that I use. How to overcome this limitation and extract at least 100 data to begin with? Below is a sample snippet. I look forward to hear from you. Thanks much in advance!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

var = "analytics"
URL = "https://in.pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=" + var

r = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
alt = []
src = []

for link in soup.find_all('img'):
    alt.append(link.get('alt'))
    src.append(link.get('src'))
```

Comment: Could be because of the home page you are trying to load has only 16 data points for you scrape !?

Comment: yeah, by using requests you are not running a browser, so most likely the page only contains 16 pins. Either look at the returned content and figure out if there is a paging mechanism or try a different tool that actually drives a browser

Comment: On Pinterest, we see more posts after scrolling down. You'll have to use `selenium` to perform the scrolling action and then extract  the page source.

Comment: Try this URL for Requesting Api... this might work for you
[https://jp.pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=$q]

Answer (score 3):

Many pages, including Pinterest, saves on bandwidth and improves the user experience by not loading content prior to use.

### To circumnavigate this issue we combine `selenium` with `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

#  Any infinity scroll URL
var = "analytics"
url = "https://in.pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=" + var 
ScrollNumber = 4  # The depth we wish to load
sleepTimer = 1    # Waiting 1 second for page to load

#  Bluetooth bug circumnavigate
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)  # path=r'to/chromedriver.exe'
driver.get(url)

for _ in range(1,ScrollNumber):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(1,100000)")
    print("scrolling")
    time.sleep(sleepTimer)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')

for link in soup.find_all('img'):
    print(link.get('src'))
    #print(link.get('alt'))
```

The following script provides an easy start if you include chromedriver.exe in your script folder.

- Chromedriver: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: This doesn't download original images.

Comment: Great quick intro into the subject of scraping infinite scroller. thanks a lot! It worked out-of-the-box!